# Some way to pull every row before a specific occurrence

Tags: r

I am having difficulty attempting to figure out how to pull all of the rows from a data frame before an occurrence. I know I can pull the first occurrence of something quite easily, but for my specific case I need to pull all cases before the specified. It is also a little trickier because they are separated into customers, so it has to be according to each customer. Some of the customers also have multiple positive occurrences.

So far I have been able to almost achieve this using for loops but there are a few incorrect rows being pulled.

Essentially I have two data sets, one where the positive case occurs only once and another where it occurs frequently.

Data set where positive case occurs only once.

```
data.frame(ID = c("103", "103", "103", "103", "103", "107", "107", "107", "107", "107"), 
           Items = c("638,193,1937,193", "3918,38327,1938,200", "860", "3982,392,3019,3928", "4038,291,493,029,192", "3604,1361,453,2782", "117", "860", "291", "203"), 
           rank = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), 
           Ordercount = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
```

Data set where positive case occurs more than once.

```
data.frame(ID = c("103", "103", "103", "103", "103", "107", "107", "107", "107", "107"), 
           Items = c("638,193,1937,193", "3918,38327,1938,200", "860", "3982,392,3019,3928", "4038,291,493,029,192", "3604,1361,453,2782", "117", "860", "291", "203"), 
           rank = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), 
           Ordercount = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1))
```

Desired Ouput

```
#First Case
data.frame(ID = c("103", "103","107", "107"), 
           Items = c("638,193,1937,193", "3918,38327,1938,200","3604,1361,453,2782", "117"), 
           rank = c(1,2,1,2), 
           Ordercount = c(0,0,0,0))
ID               Items rank Ordercount
1 103    638,193,1937,193    1          0
2 103 3918,38327,1938,200    2          0
3 107  3604,1361,453,2782    1          0
4 107                 117    2          0
```

```
# Second Case

data.frame(ID = c("103", "103","107", "107", "107"), 
           Items = c("638,193,1937,193", "3918,38327,1938,200","3604,1361,453,2782", "117", "860"), 
           rank = c(1,2,1,2,3), 
           Ordercount = c(0,0,0,0,0))

  ID               Items rank Ordercount
1 103    638,193,1937,193    1          0
2 103 3918,38327,1938,200    2          0
3 107  3604,1361,453,2782    1          0
4 107                 117    2          0
5 107                 860    3          0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to find the first occurrence of `Ordercount==1`. To find it inside each `ID` group you can use `ave` like:

```
x[as.logical(ave(x$Ordercount, x$ID, FUN=function(x) seq_along(x) < match(1, x))),]

#First Case
#   ID               Items rank Ordercount
#1 103    638,193,1937,193    1          0
#2 103 3918,38327,1938,200    2          0
#6 107  3604,1361,453,2782    1          0
#7 107                 117    2          0

# Second Case
#   ID               Items rank Ordercount
#1 103    638,193,1937,193    1          0
#2 103 3918,38327,1938,200    2          0
#6 107  3604,1361,453,2782    1          0
#7 107                 117    2          0
#8 107                 860    3          0
```

Comment: what if the ordercount is greater than one, i.e. they ordered two in the same order? could I just say equal to any number other than zero?

Comment: Yes, then use `x[as.logical(ave(x$Ordercount, x$ID, FUN=function(x) seq_along(x) < match(TRUE, x>0))),]`